# Error: cannot run the macro " xx". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with 5 VBA codes. Each VBA is recorded in one Module. So I have 5 VBA codes in 5 modules in total.

As I'm working on my workbook, each time I reach a milestone in my work, I like to save my workbook. So if my workbook's name is XX, when I save my work progress for the first time, I will save it as XX v1.0 (xx version 1.0). Next time, I will save it as XX v1.1, then XX v1.2, and so on.

While I was working on my workbook version 1.0, all my five customized FUNCTIONS were running perfectly. So the 5 modules with their respective VBA code seemed to be working properly.
Now, at some point, feeling like I had made some quite significant progress in my work, I decided to save my workbook as XX v1.1. Then all of a sudden, my modules, VBAs, and FUNCTIONS stopped working... but not entirely though, because if I clicked on the PLAY button in the Microsoft Visual Basic Application window, then the VBA code would run... but if I tried to run the MACRO from the worksheet, then I got the message:
"cannot run the macro "....". The macro may not be available in this workbook, or all macros may be disabled."
How can I solve this problem and have my macros run smoothly as they had done in the previous version of the same workbook?

I read on some forum that maybe I should click on FILE (on the ribbon), then OPTION, then TRUST, then TRUST CENTER SETTING... and then select ENABLE VBA MACROS (NOT RECOMMENDED, POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS CODE CAN RUN)... I followed the instructions, but nothing changed. So I selected the default option, which is DISABLE VBA WITH NOTIFICATION, as it sounds safer... Anyway, I can't seem to find a way to solve the problem.

Comment: How are you running the macro from the sheet?

Comment: Sorry for my strange wording. What I meant by "running from the sheet" is basically, either pressed on a button that I created on the worksheet, or simply write a customized FUNCTION of my own in a cell and press ENTER.

Comment: Did you by any chance copy form controls or shapes which have macro assigned to it from 1 workbook to the other? Best way to check is right click on the control and check which workbook is the macro referring to...

Comment: I did copy one rectangle button from one worksheet to another, not from one workbook to the other... (but I'll check on the macro assigned when I save my workbook to a higher version, meaning from XX v1.1 to XX v1.2)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this as well.  To manually unblock macros when VBA is enabled, please try this:

1. Open Windows File Explorer and go to the folder where the file is saved.
2. Right-click the file and choose **Properties** from the context menu.
3. At the bottom of the **General** tab, select the **Unblock** checkbox and select OK.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Excel (I think from 2019 onwards), macros are disabled by default. You need to explicitly enable them when you open the newly saved workbook.

Click the File tab, and then Options at the very bottom of the left bar. On the left-side pane, select Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings… .
[image]

In the Trust Center dialog box, click Macro Settings on the left and finally select the option you need (likely Enable VBA macros).
[image]

You may also want to experiment with Trust acess to the VBA project object model option (i.e. developer settings) - but I don't know what it's about.

Comment: That's the very first thing I did. But it didn't it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @DK'slittlecontribution one more thing: when you're saving, select as "file type" "Macro enabled excel workbook" - file extension .xlsm

Comment: Thanks Alexks G, yes I've always saved my Excel files containing macros with the .xlsm file extension.

Answer (score -1):

I found something !
When you save your workbook with a different workbook name, such as changing the workbook's name from XX v1.1 to XX v1.2 for some reason, macros, VBA modules, and their respective VBA codes will no longer work. Don't ask me why; I have no clue. Now, what I've done to "solve" the problem is copied the content of each module onto a notepad file, following their respective order. That is to say, I copied the first module's content (whatever its title, it doesn't matter, VBA will always consider the first module as Module 1 whatever its name) and pasted it onto notepad. I did the same with Module 2, 3, 4, and 5. Then, I deleted all the modules and exited Excel. When I launched the file again, there was a little message under the Formula box (right under the Ribbon), saying that Macros are disabled. I pressed the button right next to it to Enable macro. Then, I opened the Visual Basic window (ribbon, Developer) and created 5 modules again. In a similar fashion, I copied and pasted back each VBA code from notepad into each module, following their respective order, and now everything seems to be working properly.